# Given two list that should be one to one How to find the elements that are one to two

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given two list

```
list_a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'd']
```

and

```
list_b = ['4', '2', '1', '4', '7', '3', '8', '8']
```

The value in `list_a` should have direct correspondence to the value in `list_b` meaning that `indices` for `a` in `list_a` should have value `4` in `list_b[for i in indices]`. Then in this case, I want to fine the element that are not one to one. Such as `c` and `d` eg. `c` corresponds to `1` and `7` in list b and `d` corresponds to `3` and `8` in `list_b`.
Is there a way to get this such that

```
def func(list_a, list_b):
    ...
    # return elements in list_a that doesn't have one to one correspondence in list_b
    return [c, d]
```

okay as people say I should read more about THE stack overflow Fraternities, here is my current attempt:

```
def find_duplicate(input_list):
    seen, id_idx = set(), []
    for idx, item in enumerate(input_list):
        if item not in seen:
            seen.add(item)          # First time seeing the element
        else:
            id_idx.append(idx)
    return id_idx

def func(list_a, list_b)
    h_ids = find_duplicate(list_a)

    result = []
    for r in np.unique(list_a[h_ids]):
        idx = np.where(list_a == r)[0]
        if len(set(list_b[idx])) > 1:
            result.append(r)
    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    list_a = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'd'])
    list_b = np.array(['4', '2', '1', '4', '7', '3', '8', '8'])
    result = func(list_a, list_b)
```

Is there a faster or a more "python" method to solve this problem?
Thank you for helping.

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow. 
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: Please post the desired output because your question is confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need such a big complicated program to check this.

## Identify mismatched elements between two lists

Here's how I would do it.

Iterate through `list_a`. If the value in `list_a` is a first instance, store it into a dictionary as key with value = value from list_b in same position. Then check next time the same key in list_a shows up. If the value is not the same, then print the value out. Here, we are assuming the first occurrence is always the correct one.

```
list_a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'd']
list_b = ['4', '2', '1', '4', '7', '3', '8', '8']

d = {}
for i,val in enumerate(list_a):
    if val in d and d[val] != list_b[i]:
        print (f'list_a \'{val}\' and list_b \'{list_b[i]}\' in position {i} are not matching')
    else: d[val] = list_b[i]
```

Output of this will be:

```
list_a 'c' and list_b '7' in position 4 are not matching
list_a 'd' and list_b '8' in position 7 are not matching
```

## Ver 2: Mismatched elements between two lists

Let's say you want all the values that mismatched between the two lists. Then you can do something like this to get the values as well.

```
list_a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'd', 'a']
list_b = ['4', '2', '1', '5', '7', '3', '8', '8', '5']

d = {}
for i,val in enumerate(list_a):
    d.setdefault(val,[]).append(list_b[i])

d = {k:set(v) for k,v in d.items() if len(set(v)) > 1}
if d:
    print ('The following values mismatch')
    for k,v in d.items():
        print (f'The values for \'{k}\' are {v}')
else:
    print ('All values in both lists are good')
```

The output of this (i edited the input lists) will be:

```
The following values mismatch
The values for 'a' are {'4', '5'}
The values for 'c' are {'7', '1'}
The values for 'd' are {'8', '3'}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is much simpler than my approach.